# resize and replace image using PHP

Tags: php, image

I am trying to resize and replace an image uploaded by the user but the most I can do is resize and output as another file.  I have used the library image magician to resize.

If someone can explain how I can do it without using the library it would be better.

```
public function add() {
     $f=Base::instance()->get('FILES');
     $fext=pathinfo ($f['usrimg']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
     $this->copyFrom('POST');
     $this->save();
     $newName=str_pad($this->_id,5,"0").'.'.$fext;
     move_uploaded_file($f['usrimg']['tmp_name'], $newName);
     $this->load('id='.$this->_id);
     $this->set('photo',$newName);
     $this->update();  

     require_once('php_image_magician.php');
     $magicianObj = new imageLib($newName);
     $magicianObj->resizeImage(100, 200);
     $magicianObj->saveImage('q.jpg', 100);
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to use `gd` or `gd2` library. It is very complete and easy-to-use.

Comment: can you give me an example please in the context of sizing the image down if it is above a certain size @AmirZojaji

Comment: I brout it in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `gd` library, for example you can use this code for resizing jpeg images:

```
  $image=file_get_contents('image.jpg');
  $src=imagecreatefromstring($image);
  $x=imagesx($src);
  $y=imagesy($src);
  $y1=100; //new width
  $x1=intval($y1*$x/$y); //new height proprtional to new width
  $dst=imagecreatetruecolor($x1,$y1);
  imagecopyresized($dst,$src,0,0,0,0,$x1,$y1,$x,$y);
  header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
  imagejpeg($dst);
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the variable $doc_row? when i try to implement this i get a message that it is undefined

Comment: nothing seems to happen when i add this code into the function add. the image size stays the same

Comment: You must have an image file beside php file named image.jpg that this program changes its size. Also you must have `gd` extension enabled in `php.ini` file and also `error_reporting=E_ALL` and `display_errors=1` to view any error or warning or notice.